# Can apps written in Oracle ADF 11.1.1.6 run in the ADF 11.1.1.7 runtime?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have written an application using 11.1.1.7 only to find out that the server I need to deploy to has 11.1.1.6.  I have extensively used the panelgridlayout in the app which is not a feature of 11.1.1.6.

Can't I just update the server's runtime to 11.1.1.7 without breaking apps written specifically for 11.1.1.6?

In other words, does 11.1.1.7 remove features from 11.1.1.6 that would break existing applications?

Answer (score 0):

An 11.1.1.6 app should run seamlessly in 11.1.1.7.
11.1.1.7 adds features and fixes bugs, so upgrading the 11.1.1.6 to it should be smooth.

Comment: I'd suggest to do a full application test/check. Since fixed bugs and/or new features can change current application behavior or even break it.